# The HTML markup to include the image of Rango in the about template was not found

Tags: python, html, django

While creating a web app in Django, I've encountered a small issue. There seems to be a problem with my about template referencing. This is about.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load staticfiles %} <!-- New line -->
{% load static %}

<html> <head>
    <title>Rango</title> </head>
<body>
<h1>Rango says...</h1>
<div>
    here is the about page. <br />
    <strong>This tutorial has been put together by Oliver Alan Stafurik</strong><br />
</div>
<div>
    <a href="/rango/">Index</a><br />
    <img src="{% static 'images/rango.jpg' %}"alt="Picture of Rango" /> <!-- New line -->
    <img src="{% static 'cat.jpg %'}" alt="Picture of a Cat" />
</div> </body>
</html>
```

Here's my settings.py:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))        TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
MEDIA_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')   
STATICFILES_DIRS = [STATIC_DIR,]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'    
    
MEDIA_ROOT = [MEDIA_DIR, ]
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

And here's my urls.py:

```
    from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.urls import include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from rango import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('rango/', include('rango.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I'm getting a traceback: `File "/Users/stovifo/tango_with_django_project/tango_with_django_project/rango/tests_chapter4.py", line 254, in test_about_contains_rango     self.assertTrue(required_str in self.about_response.content.decode(), f"{FAILURE_HEADER}The HTML markup to include the image of Rango in the about template was not found. It needs to match exactly what we are looking for. Check the book.{FAILURE_FOOTER}") AssertionError: False is not true :`

**EDIT:**
The issue was just a small typo, where instead of `"{% static 'cat.jpg'%}"` I have typed in `"{% static 'cat.jpg %'}"`.

Comment: Add any code/errors as **text** formatted as code, **not** as images. Please look at [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Oh okay will do

Comment: `+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)` You need to add this also. You only add the media urls in your code.

Comment: like this? + `static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)`

Comment: still getting the same error after that

Comment: Where do you get the error? Add the full error traceback to your question.

Comment: `File "/Users/stovifo/tango_with_django_project/tango_with_django_project/rango/tests_chapter4.py", line 254, in test_about_contains_rango
    self.assertTrue(required_str in self.about_response.content.decode(), f"{FAILURE_HEADER}The HTML markup to include the image of Rango in the about template was not found. It needs to match exactly what we are looking for. Check the book.{FAILURE_FOOTER}")
AssertionError: False is not true : `

Comment: Do you see or find the image when you actually go to the html page? If this was a failing test wouldn't it be more indicative to add the tests code to the question? Also instead of adding the traceback in the comments you should [edit] your question and add it there.

Comment: I see the rango picture, don't see the cat one. Thanks for the tips, edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this you have just forgot to put 'cat.jpg' :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load staticfiles %} <!-- New line -->
{% load static %}

<html> <head>
    <title>Rango</title> </head>
<body>
<h1>Rango says...</h1>
<div>
    here is the about page. <br />
    <strong>This tutorial has been put together by Oliver Alan Stafurik</strong><br />
</div>
<div>
    <a href="/rango/">Index</a><br />
    <img src="{% static 'images/rango.jpg' %}"alt="Picture of Rango" />
    <img src="{% static 'cat.jpg' %}" alt="Picture of a Cat" /> <!-- you make a mistake here -->
</div> </body>
</html>
```